# SQL Server - Non-reindexed Database

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning, maintenance

I have a database that has not been reindexed in the last 5 years.

I want a yes or no answer if databases without index maintenance and "Missing Rows" are related to each other.

Comment: Sounds like you have two problems that you are trying to combine into one? Are you waiting on peer approval before dealing with either?

Comment: Missing rows is my problem, im not expert with databases and someone advices me to reindex the tables, im not so sure if that would really help.

Comment: How are you identifying that rows are missing? Why do you think the only answer could be corruption? You need to explain your actual problem, not throw out two guesses as to what might be causing the unstated problem.

Comment: They may not be related, but that doesn't mean reindexing wouldn't help fix the missing rows issue. Still, you would be right to still be concerned about the *cause* of the missing rows issue.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm just looking for possibilities. actually I'm not in charge on database administration and have no skills to manage it, I want to give an answer to my boss regarding with this problem as much as possible that's why.

Comment: @RDFozz do you mean that if i reindex my table(s) there is a possibility to have a new/restored row?

Comment: No - I was thinking that if the missing row was in the index, then the reindexing would fix that.

Comment: @RDFozz can you elaborate this "if the missing row was in the index,"? thanks

Comment: How did you define "missing rows"  like @AaronBertrand asked?

Comment: @TomV missing rows = can't find in the table

Comment: Yes obviously, but why do you think they should be in the table?

Comment: @Newbie_is - Ignore my comment - not intimately familiar with the error. A messed up (non-clustered) index can be fixed by reindexing, since the table is fine. As noted, this error is almost certainly speaking of a row missing from the table. If the table has missing data, reindexing shouldn't magically make it appear.

Comment: @TomV I have two tables: `Schools`, `Students` (no foreign key defined) - some `SchoolID` in the `Students` table are not in `Schools` table. * there is no delete feature in the client application * but let us assumed that the database is not mishandled/hacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Database index fragmentation and missing rows are not related. Fragmentation is mismatch in ordering of physical pages and clustering key. A fragmentation can never cause rows to go "missing".
2. No a database without index is NOT prone to corruption. Index just makes things faster period.

Comment: is there a chance to have a different row count after reindex process?

Comment: Not unless you've hit a bug in SQL Server. And I haven't heard about such bug.